# parsing C code using python

Tags: python, parsing

I have a huge C file (~100k lines) which I need to be able to parse. Mainly I need to be able to get details about individual fields of every structure (like field name and type for every field in the structure) from its definition. Is there a good(open source, which i can use in my code) way to do this already? Or should I write my own parser for this. If I have to write my own, can anyone suggest a good place to start? I have never worked with python before.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample? Are you needing to test a C compiler (and support unions, structs-within-structs, typedefs, the preprocessor, etc. or just get data out of simple structs? Something tells me that this C file should be JSON, CSV, a database, or another *data* format, not a 100k LOC C file...

Comment: ... and you probably haven't written a C parser before, either.  You don't want to do this yourself; C is much more complicated than you think it is:  macros, preprocessor conditionals, includes, ambiguous syntax, vendor-specific syntax, symbol table construction, ...   Find an existing C parser that has had extensive validation and use that, even if the C parser isn't implemented in Python.  If you want to use Python to process the results,  fine, but don't confuse Python for the solution ["I never worked with Python before" is not a good sign that way is going to lead to success.]

Comment: ... I suggest you consider GCCXML, which contains a C parser and exports the kind of data you want as XML.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing) for an extensive list of parsing tools available for Python. Specifically, for parsing c code, try the [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser)

Answer (score 11):

The right way to do this is almost certainly to interface with the front-end of an existing compiler, such as gcc, then work with the intermediate representation, rather than attempting to create your own parser, in any language.

However, [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser), as suggested by Dhara might well be a good substitute, and definitely better than any attempt to roll your own.