# finding keywords frequency in a c code using python excluding comments

Tags: python

I want to create a program, that can count the frequency of keywords used in a `C` code, excluding the commented ones or inside `printf` command.

```
def counting(f, word):
    counter = 0
    for w in f.split():
        if word==w:
            counter += 1
    return counter

key=open('c_keywords.txt')
keyw=key.read().split()
file=open('a1.cpp').read()

for key in keyw:
    x = counting(file,key)
    if x != 0:
        print (key, ":", x)
```

Comment: [parsing C code using python](//stackoverflow.com/q/11143095)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What exactly is your question/problem? You only provided code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing C code using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143095/parsing-c-code-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

> Here is an example of how to do it with a textfile, you can edit the text.txt and use your C code file instead

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as doc:
    print('opened txt')
    for words in doc:
        wordlist = words.split()     

for numbers in range(len(wordlist)):
        for inner_numbers in range(len(wordlist)):
            if inner_numbers != numbers:
                if wordlist[numbers] == wordlist[inner_numbers]:
                    print('word: %s == %s' %(wordlist[numbers], wordlist[inner_numbers]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
f = open('keywords_c.txt')

count = 0
words = []

for x in f:
    w = x.split()
    for a in w:
        words.append(a)
print(words)

cpp = open('Simple_c.cpp')

program = []

for y in cpp:

    if y.startswith('printf'):
        continue
    elif y.startswith('//'):
        continue
    else:
        w = y.split()
        for b in w:
            if any(b in s for s in words):
                count +=1


print(count)
```